# jQuery hide selectMenu?

Tags: jquery, hide, select-menu

I'm using jQuery's selectMenu on a select tag like this.

```
$('#ddlReport').selectmenu()
```

in certain cases I want to hide it, and I can't figure out how.

this doesn't work:

```
$('#ddlReport').selectmenu().hide();
```

neither does this

```
$('#ddlReport').hide();
```

anyone?

Comment: can you show us the demo here http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Would this work? `$("#ddlReport").next(".ui-selectmenu-button").hide();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the demos [here](http://view.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/demos/selectmenu/default.html) and [here](http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/branches/labs/selectmenu/index.html), it seems selectmenu works by appending a

```
<span class="ui-selectmenu-button">
or (probably different selectmenu versions?)
<a ... class="ui-selectmenu ...">
```

after the original select, containing the artificial select.

You could try accessing that using

```
$('#ddlReport').next('.ui-selectmenu .ui-selectmenu-button').hide();
```

Though it sounds like it may use other classes (instead of `-button`). This is also a kind of hackish workaround and I'm sure the plugin contains some way *intended* to let you access the newly appended menu.

Edit: Looking through the code in the second demo, it doesn't seem like there is any preprogrammed way to access the new select in that version at least.

Comment: I cannot believe that jQuery mobile does not hide these spans automatically on reinitialization. I've tried `$('#my_select').prop('disabled', false).hide().selectmenu("refresh")` but it did not work correctly. Bogus "selects" were still visible. Finally I was forced to use approach similar to this answer `.prop('disabled', true).parents('.ui-select').hide();` Thanks to Armatus

Answer (score 6):

After losing a few hours trying to figure this out.  I finally wrapped the thing in a `<div>` and just show/hide on the div.  Certainly far from elegant but it keeps me out of the jq mobile innards.

Answer (score 5):

With newer versions of jQueryUI (I'm working with version 1.11.4), simply use the "widget" attribute:

```
$("#element").selectmenu( "widget" ).hide();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 $("#ddlReport").parent().hide();
```

works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Armatus!

Just want to say that for me this worked:

```
$('#ddlReport').next('.ui-selectmenu').hide();
```

Without the .ui-selectmenu-button class which doesn't exist in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution!

```
$("#yourSelectId").parent().hide();
```

wrapping with a div or forcing usage of button classes are definitively more complicated.